# calling a property from method

Tags: c#, silverlight

can I call my property `TaskAll` from the method `Task`

My code is

```
private ObservableCollection<TaskExecutionHistoryModel> _TaskAll;
public ObservableCollection<TaskExecutionHistoryModel> TaskAll
{
   get{ return _TaskAll;}
   set
   {
      _TaskAll = value;
      base.NotifyPropertyChanged(x => x.TaskAll);
   }
}

public Task(ObservableCollection<TaskExecutionHistoryModel> ExecutionHistory)
{
}
```

Comment: yes you can; have you tried calling them?

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
public Task(ObservableCollection<TaskExecutionHistoryModel> ExecutionHistory)
{
   ObservationCollection<TaskExecutionHistoryModel> model = TaskAll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by simply calling it:

```
public Task(ObservableCollection<TaskExecutionHistoryModel> ExecutionHistory)
{
   TaskAll = someValue;
   someOtherValue = TaskAll;
}
```